# Missing analytics function using PARTITION BY in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to use the LAG function in combination with PARTITION BY to calculate the difference in time stamps.

```
SELECT
 uuid,
 event_info,
 TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(event_time) - LAG(TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(event_time),1) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY event_time ASC)  
FROM
 [DataSet.TableName]
ORDER BY
 uuid,
 event_time
```

But that generates an error from bigquery saying "Error: Missing function in Analytic Expression at: 4.95 - 4.153"

However, if I split the line 4th line into two parts as

```
 TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(event_time) as time,
 LAG(TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC(event_time),1) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY event_time ASC) as previousTime,
```

Then it runs just fine.  The work around would be to use the 'fix' above, and then wrap the entire query in another query so that I can perform the calculation as

```
 previousTime - time as difference
```

But that seems a bit hacky and other SQL variants don't have a problem with the query.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be fixed in BigQuery's standard SQL dialect - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/enabling-standard-sql

Note, that instead of `TIMESTAMP_TO_MSEC` function in legacy SQL, you will need to use equivalent `UNIX_MILLIS` function.

Comment: Thanks Mosha.  If I select that option and then save it as a view, am I safe to presume the option will be saved w/ the view?

Comment: Sorry - no view support for standard SQL yet, but it is coming soon.

Comment: I cannot give definitive timelines, but it is under active development, so I would expect that if everything goes well, it will be available in couple of months.

Comment: I can't see the UNIX_MILLIS function in the documentation. Can you point it out to me, please? Thanks!

re: deployment to views: That's great, but for now I'll have to use the nested select statements solution. :) Thanks for your helpful info!

Comment: UNIX_MILLIS and other timestamp conversion functions are documented here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/functions-and-operators#additional-date-and-timestamp-conversion-functions